# Normalization till 3rd normal form

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, normalize

Process the given scheme to its third normal form

```
Repayment (borrower_id,name,address,loan_amount,request_date,repayment_date,request_amount)
```

what i have done

```
Borrower(borrower_id,address)
Request(request_id,request_date,borrower_id,loan_id)
Repayment(repayment_id,request_date,borrower_id)
Loan(loan_id,loan_amount)
```

Please help me if im wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you went badly wrong in at least three different directions.

**Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes.**

You started with one id number: borrower_id. You ended with four id numbers: borrower_id, request_id, loan_id, repayment_id.

**Normalization doesn't drop attributes.**

You dropped "name". Granted, that's a bad name for an attribute. (Whose name is it? Borrower's name? Bank's name? Loan officer's name?) But you don't get to just throw it away.

**Normalization relies on functional dependencies.**

A functional dependency usually looks like this: A->B. You don't show any functional dependencies.